# Rails couldn't find a valid model for Preferences association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to add new record to my DB, but I got this error:
[image]

This is my schema.rb:
[image]

And this is my method create:
[image]

And this is my form to add a new record:

[image]

The param is sending correctly, but when I click on Upload button, nothing is happen, and if I try to add the record from the rails console, I got the error of the first image. I'm a new dev of RoR, someone can help me please?, Thanks!!

Comment: Please post code as formatted text rather than pictures of text.

Comment: Why are you showing a videos controller if the error is for something called category? You'll also need to show the relevant model class(es).

Comment: Yeah, but in the categories conroller I don't have nothing, I inserted the category from rails console, and the video table has a foerign key to the category table, so, it should not be a problem, because the category table is not empty.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant models there's no way to help. It says you're missing a relationship; are you? Or incorrectly referencing a model, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the related models and their associations nothing is clear, because, it seems like your model associations are causing this error.
Model associations depict the relations between models (if its one-one, one-many and such) known as inheritance, very important concept in any object oriented programming. this is the way we implement it in rails
Go through this [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).
It might help you get better understanding of rails associations.

Comment: Relations are not "inheritance" or OOP.  Relations are about relating entities (tables) in a relational database.